# NMS does not work in tensorflow-lite quantized model

Tags: tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, google-coral

Recently I've used tensorflow object detection API to train object detector (ssd mobilenet v1). I want to run detection on [Coral Edge TPU](https://coral.ai/products/m2-accelerator-ae/) so I used quantization-aware training.
I added the following section to my pipeline.config to enable quantization:

```
graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 1800
    activation_bits: 8
    weight_bits: 8
  }
}
```

When training finished I converted it into .pb using the following command:

```
python $TFAPIPATH/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
 --pipeline_config_path $CONFIG_NAME \
 --trained_checkpoint_prefix $CHECKPOINT_PREFIX \
 --output_directory $OUTPUT_DIR \
 --add_postprocessing_op true
```

And after that - generated .tflite file using

```
--input_file=$INPUT_FILE \ 
--output_file=$OUTPUT_FILE \
--input_shapes=1,200,800,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \ 
--mean_values=128 \
--std_values=128 \
--change_concat_input_ranges=false \
--allow_custom_ops
```

I run detection from C++ code using tflite library I compiled myself (Ubuntu 18.04 x64). I used the tensorflow repository revision mentioned in Edge TPU documentation to make sure that it is compatible with the libedgetpu (version 13.0).

Detection ran successfully but I had huge accuracy drop ~10% in comparison to non-quantized version. I found that large amount of this loss is caused by the fact that no NMS step is performed by tflite. I observed an image with two almost completely overlapped objects detected.

As far as I understand tflite supports nms operation and ssd mobilenet v1 network which is converted to tflite with the recommended tools (as I mentioned above) should do nms. But for some reason in my case it doesn't work. I had to add nms step as a post-process operation to my C++ code to improve model's performance.

Am I missing something, or maybe something is wrong with the conversion commands I used?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi after converting from .pb to .tflite, have you verify the model's accuracy?
Just wondering if it's a problem due to tflite conversion or the edgetpu compiler.

Comment: @NamVu Hi, I didn't compare accuracy of .pb and .tflite, but there were almost no differences between results of .tflite model running on CPU and the model compiled from it by edgetpu compiler and running on TPU. So I'm almost sure that it's not a problem with the edgetpu compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Humn, the accuracy drops maybe a separate issue that should be addressed, however I don't think it is because nms is not performed. When you export the pb model to `.tflite` with this flags: `--add_postprocessing_op true`, non max suppression should be included in the post processing ops. The code for that is here if you want to explore: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc

I know it's been a long time, but you may want to check your config again at this point and lower the iou_threshold to get less output boxes: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync.config#L130